# How can I monitor the ports which are in use based on bandwidth utilized?

Tags: java, network-security

I have to monitor the ports which are in use under the server (i.e. all the clients who are accessing the network) and especially it must be made in a such way that it should monitor based on the bandwidth utilized.

It should report the anonymous ports (the uncommon ports which are not for any specific application or protocol) which are being used beyond some threshold value (for example, 200KB or 2000KB). Can this be implemented easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd check out [jNetPcap](http://jnetpcap.com/). I used this years ago to do something similar.  How 'easy' it would be for you to use and implement the solution you're looking for is hard for me to answer.

Note, I believe it does require installation at one of the communication endpoints.  If that doesn't suit you, maybe look into getting data directly from routers or other network hardware.

Comment: @peter : Thanks for your quick response. Atleast can a firewall be developed in java to scan all local and remote ports which are in use(open) and also with blocking functionality?

Comment: re: building a firewall.. I'm sure it's possible, but that's beyond my experience so I'm afraid I can't help much there